# Having trouble with file sharing between two Macs

Tags: macos, mac, network, mac-mini, mac-pro

Due to slow Internet I have two Mac mini's on two different networks and moving data between these two Macs have been a problem for me as disabling my hard drive and moving it to the other Mac is starting to annoy me a lot. I move a lot of data daily and I really want to just find a way to make it easier for me. I use one more than the other and want to keep one as my main one and the other will be just for monitoring and quick use.

So is there a way that I can connect these Macs that are on two different networks via Intranet? (Or maybe have like an offline Dropbox connected via FireWire?)

Comment: This is even trickier without more data. Why would slow internet make two Mac Mini be on different networks? Why not string a cable between the two and have gigabit or better speeds? What does "disabling my hard drive and moving it to the other mac" do? are you implementing a sneaker net for data transfer?

Comment: Ive just did some reading about Airdrop

Comment: You don't mention the distance separating these two minis. Are they in the same room, house, neighborhood, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the distance between the Macs, you would connect them as follows:

- Thunderbolt networking
- Ethernet direct connect
- Ethernet to a gigabit switch
- Ethernet to an ethernet switch
- Ethernet to a router
- Wireless to a router
- Using the slow internet you mention

Comment: Since you commented AirDrop - that is far far far slower than an ethernet cable between the two devices, so unless you really can't string a cable, wired is superior to wireless for large data transfers.